# created field in cakephp join table

Tags: cakephp-2.0, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have the following in $this->request->data in a form post:

```
Array
(
    [Customer] => Array
        (
            [first_name] => Test
            [last_name] => test
            [dob] => Array
                (
                    [month] => 11
                    [day] => 10
                    [year] => 2014
                )

        )

    [Service] => Array
        (
            [Service] => 1
        )

)
```

which also creates a record in a join table `customers_services` (model `CustomersService`).

What I want to do is touch the created field in the join table but not sure how. Any ideas anyone? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't really understand what you're trying to do.

By default, for every Model save, created and modified will be automatically set by CakePHP itself.